# Are the Children of the moon harmless to humans?

Tags: twilight

In Twilight, are the werewolves completely harmless to humans?

Comment: Very little information is supplied in the novels about the Children of the Moon. It seems unlikely that you're going to get an answer that isn't pure speculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we *know* of the werewolves from that universe is:

- There is no instance on-screen, nor any reference to an instance off-screen, of a werewolf attacking a human. (In particular, when vampires start killing people, there is no sense of it being "yet another" spate of unexplained attacks that happens all the time.)
- Werewolf shifting in Twilight is voluntary, and even in wolf shape, the shifter appears to be in full control of their actions.
- The Quileute tribe has a peace with the Cullen vampires that is based on their vow not to attack and feed on humans.
- The tribe are prepared to break their peace with the Cullens for biting Bella, even though she is willing.
- The tribe is willing to cooperate with their "natural enemy" -- vampires -- in order to defend the humans from carnivorous vampires.

That's all the canon information we have. It is not very conclusive: in particular, we don't know anything about the wolves' behavior in the past, nor if there are other clans of wolves that may have different rules. We also don't know how much of their behavior is due to a desire to protect humans, vs. a desire to protect their own hunting grounds from vampires (with humans being a convenient excuse.)

However, we aren't given any indication that the werewolves are a danger to humans. Purely *my opinion*, but given how often Jacob took the moral high ground towards Edward, I would have expected Edward to divulge any similar information he knew about the wolves.

Answer (score 1):

The actual [**Children of the Moon**](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Moon) spread by biting humans. Therefore they are **clearly not harmless**.

> While in their werewolf form, the Children of the Moon lose their
>   human consciousness; they are feral rather than rational. Usually,
>   they run alone, or with one companion of the opposite gender. Children
>   of the Moon cannot breed in their animal form; they can spread their
>   species only by infecting other humans through a bite.

As for the [**Quileute werewolves**](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Shape-shifter), they seem mostly harmless to humans as Mike Edenfield argues in [his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16300/43787). However, new shape-shifters are shown having problems controlling their temper. For example, [Sam Uley](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Sam_Uley) attacked [Emily Young](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Emily_Young) when he lost control of himself. This is probably the worst consequence of shape-shifting shown. Even though it was an accident, Quileute werewolves **can't be said to be completely harmless** to humans because of this.

> Sam, outraged, lost control of himself, phased into a werewolf and
>   scarred her badly enough that 'mauled by a bear' was the only
>   plausible cover story. Bella describes the wound as three deep scars
>   that run along the right side of her face and distort her features,
>   pulling down the corner of her eye and her mouth.

Excerpts from the Twilight Saga Wiki.